# Trying to solve date conditional in MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to list upcoming deliveries that can still be chosen for shipping. Each of these deliveries requires a certain amount of lead-time to ship - so it's not realistic to expect your delivery to come tomorrow if you order at 5pm the day before.

The deliveries table defines a "leadTime" which is an integer of days and also a "nextDate" which contains a date field in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. I need to filter out the rows where the "nextDate" is at least one day away - or rather, one day away if before 10am and two days away if after 10am.

```
SELECT d.* FROM delivery d
WHERE d.nextDate >= DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL d.leadTime DAY )
ORDER BY d.nextDate ASC, d.id ASC
```

For example, (assuming a leadTime of *one day*). If it was 9am Wednesday - I can see all records *from Thursday on*. However, if it's 11am Wednesday I can only see *from Friday on* (since it's after 10am there isn't enough time to prepare).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 14 HOUR)` in place of `CURRENT_DATE` or, combining the whole thing together:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     delivery
WHERE    nextDate >= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 14 HOUR + INTERVAL leadTime DAY)
ORDER BY nextDate ASC, id ASC
```